# To list all the fields of a class and put them in a list if they match a desired type

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, field, gettype

The title is quite confusing, but what i want to achieve is calling a method to all (swing) buttons / labels in my class. 
(to make them all look similar)

Something a bit like this:

```
for(Button btn: components)
  btn.setThisTheme();
```

where `components[]` is a array of JComponent-s.
So far i have tried this:

```
    // at beginning of class
    private LinkedList<JComponent> components = new LinkedList<>();
    private Field[] fields = ToDo.class.getDeclaredFields().length;


   // in constructor
   for (Field field: fields) {
            if(field.getType() == JComponent.class) { 
                components.add(field); // how to do this? 
// field is a Field and i need to convert it into the variable it represents...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an array of `null`s.

```
private Field[] fields = new Field[ToDo.class.getDeclaredFields().length];
```

You should be able to use the array returned by `getDeclaredFields` directly.

```
private Field[] fields = ToDo.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Almost certainly you can do what you want to do better without reflection.

Comment: welp, thank you. I didnt notice such a simple mistake, sometimes its better to have someone else read your code :)

Comment: Hmm... actually i have another problem in the same matter, ill edit the question

Comment: @KamilSuhak You should ask a new question to ask a new question. However, you need an actual instance for the `Field` to read. `Field` itself refers to all objects, it may even be a static field. So replace `field` with something like `(JComponent)(field.get(this))`.